# vim find and replace around a string

Tags: vim, regular-expression

In VIM, if, for example, I have the text

```
http://a.com
http://b.com
```

is it possible to find all lines (the whole line) and replace it with something before and after it, such as:

```
<a href="http://a.com">http://a.com</a>
<a href="http://b.com">http://b.com</a>
```

Note that the text from every line is repeated. Once for the href and another for the text.

Comment: If you use Vim, you may also be interested in the [`vi` and Vim stack exchange](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/substitute).  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:%s:.*:<a href="&">&</a>:
```

Same as in ed/sed/perl...

Another less `ex` and more `vim`-like way would be: if you know how to do it once for a line, record it as a macro and then run `:%normal @m` where `m` is that macro.

Like (in normal mode): `qmS<a href="<Ctrl-R>""><Ctrl-R>"</a><Esc>q` to record the macro.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It gave me this error:E748: No previously used register
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: @AlexandreSantos, oops. I had overlooked that `|` was special. Should work better  with `:`

Answer (score 1):

why do you use the Pipe?

```
:%s/.*/\<a href=\"&\"\>&\<\/a\>/g
```

(mark all command strings with \ )

Comment: You don't need to escape the `<` or `>`.

Comment: On the right-hand side of `s/x/y/`, none of `<`, `"` or `>` are special, they don't need to be escaped. `/` is only special if you use it as the delimiter. `g` is superfluous.